# Show that a positive integer $a>1$ is a perfect square (i.e., the square of an integer)...

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

if and only is in the prime decomposition of $a$ all the exponent are even integers. I don't understand what the question is asking. If I'm interpreting this correctly....any $a>1$ such as 9 would work. I don't get the *iff* proposition.

Comment: There are two claims here:
1) If $a>1$ is a perfect square, then in its prime decomposition all the exponents are even integers.
2) If in the prime decomposition of $a>1$ all exponents are even integers, then $a$ is a perfect square.

Comment: Let's say $a=9$ since $9$ is a perfect square. Then it's prime decomposition, $3*3$ has an exponent of $2$. Is that what the first claim is referring to?

Comment: I don't see the issue here, a perfect square by definition is $x^2$ where $x$ is some integer therefore $x = p_1^{x_1}p_2^{x_2}...$ therefore the perfect square is $x^2 = p_1^{2x_1}p_2^{2x_2}...$.

Comment: If that's the case, I need help proving both ways because I don't see a way through it.

Comment: @nyorkr23 Yes, the prime decomposition of $9$ is $3^2$, so all exponents are even. To prove the forward direction, suppose $a=b^2$, and try to write the prime decomposition of $a$ in terms of the prime decomposition for $b$. The reverse implication should be straightforward because you have a product of squares (primes to even powers).

Comment: Then $b=rational a$. Therefore, $b$ is a prime number. For the other direction if $x^2={p_1^2x_1}{p_2^2x_2}...$ and square root the product, I would be left with a product of primes? Would the two proofs make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $a$ is a perfect square, $a=k^{2}$ for some $k\in\mathbb{N}$. Since $a>1$, $k$ must also be greater that $1$. Thus by FTA $$k=p_{1}^{x_{1}}p_{2}^{x_{2}}...p_{l}^{x_{l}}$$ $$a=p_{1}^{y_{1}}p_{2}^{y_{2}}...p_{m}^{y_{l}}$$Since the factorization is unique we must have $m=l$ and $y_{i}=2x_{i}$ for $1\leq i \leq l$. So all the exponents are even.

If the exponents in the PF of $a$ are all even, the the factorization has the form, $$a=p_{1}^{2x_{1}}p_{2}^{2x_{2}}...p_{l}^{2x_{l}}$$ Since there are a finite number of terms, we can write it as, $$a=(p_{1}^{x_{1}}p_{2}^{x_{2}}...p_{l}^{x_{l}})^{2}$$$$a=(k)^{2}$$ Thus $a$ is a perfect.

Comment: How do you prove it the other way and why is $y_i=2x_i$?

Comment: Both ways are proven. Perhaps I should add an extra break. Second, uniqueness gives the equation in question.

Comment: I see why it's $2x_i$. Since we want $a=k^2$, you had to set the $k$ equation to $k^2$ which meant squaring the exponents. Oh I get your proofs. Thanks.

Comment: I have a general question. When we're proving a proof of any sort, do we also have to prove its uniqueness?

Comment: It depends on what your trying to prove. Part of the fundamental theorem of arithmetic says the prime factorization of any integer greater than 1 is unique. So if you want to prove the FTA you need to prove uniqueness.